# DateTimePickerModal how to get time in 12 hour clock format?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a DateTimePickerModal here, and I want to get the time as 12 hour clock format instead of 24 hour clock format. Currently, the code below I have only shows time in 24 hour clock format in the TextInput. What should I do to get the time in 12 hour clock format?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';

export default function ShareExample() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState('');
  const [isTimePickerVisible, setTimePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showTimePicker = () => {
    setTimePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideTimePicker = () => {
    setTimePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = (time) => {
    setTime(time);
    hideTimePicker();
  };

  const getTime = () => {
    let tempTime = time.toString().split(' ');
    return time !== ''
      ? `${tempTime[4]}`
      : '';
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        value={getTime()}
        placeholder="Time..."
      />
      <Button onPress={showTimePicker} title="Set Time" />
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isTimePickerVisible}
        mode="time"
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        onCancel={hideTimePicker}
      />
      <Text>{time.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 50,
  },
  textInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginBottom: 5,
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable it using this prop `is24Hour` is available on android.

```
<DateTimePickerModal
  isVisible={isTimePickerVisible}
  mode="time"
  onConfirm={handleConfirm}
  onCancel={hideTimePicker}
  is24Hour={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answer. In **Android**, we can disable by passing is24Hour props.

```
<DataTimePickerModal
is24hour={false}
/>
```

In **IOS**, we can use **locale** props by assigning "en_GB"

```
<DataTimePickerModal
  mode="time"
  locale="en_GB" // Use "en_GB" here
/>
```

Comment: Hey there! The "above" answer is subject to change at any time. Please include all relevant information in your own answer.